# SOLID - does Single responsibility principle apply to methods in a class?

Tags: php, oop, solid-principles, single-responsibility-principle

I am not sure whether this method inside my class is violating Single responsibility principle,

```
public function save(Note $note)
{
    if (!_id($note->getid())) {

        $note->setid(idGenerate('note'));

        $q = $this->db->insert($this->table)
                      ->field('id', $note->getid(), 'id');

    } else {
        $q = $this->db->update($this->table)
                      ->where('AND', 'id', '=', $note->getid(), 'id');
    }

    $q->field('title', $note->getTitle())
      ->field('content', $note->getContent());

    $this->db->execute($q);

    return $note;
}
```

Basically it does **two jobs** in a method - insert or update.

Should I **separate** it into two methods instead to comply with Single responsibility principle?

But SRP is meant for **classes only**, isn't it? Does it apply to the methods inside a class?

SRP -

> a class should have only a single responsibility (i.e. only one
>   potential change in the software's specification should be able to
>   affect the specification of the class)

**EDIT:**

Another method for listing notes (including many different type of listings), searching notes, etc...

```
public function getBy(array $params = array())
{
    $q = $this->db->select($this->table . ' n')
                  ->field('title')
                  ->field('content')
                  ->field('creator', 'creator', 'id')
                  ->field('created_on')
                  ->field('updated_on');

    if (isset($params['id'])) {
        if (!is_array($params['id'])) {
            $params['id'] = array($params['id']);
        }

        $q->where('AND', 'id', 'IN', $params['id'], 'id');
    }

    if (isset($params['user_id'])) {
        if (!is_array($params['user_id'])) {
            $params['user_id'] = array($params['user_id']);
        }

        # Handling of type of list: created / received
        if (isset($params['type']) && $params['type'] == 'received') {
            $q
                ->join(
                    'inner',
                    $this->table_share_link . ' s',
                    's.target_id = n.id AND s.target_type = \'note\''
                )
                ->join(
                    'inner',
                    $this->table_share_link_permission . ' p',
                    'p.share_id = s.share_id'
                )
                # Is it useful to know the permission assigned?
                ->field('p.permission')
                # We don't want get back own created note
                ->where('AND', 'n.creator', 'NOT IN', $params['user_id'], 'uuid');
            ;

            $identity_id = $params['user_id'];

            # Handling of group sharing
            if (isset($params['user_group_id']) /*&& count($params['user_group_id'])*/) {
                if (!is_array($params['user_group_id'])) {
                    $params['user_group_id'] = array($params['user_group_uuid']);
                }

                $identity_id = array_merge($identity_id, $params['user_group_id']);
            }

             $q->where('AND', 'p.identity_id', 'IN', $identity_id, 'id');

        } else {
            $q->where('AND', 'n.creator', 'IN', $params['user_id'], 'id');
        }
    }

    # If string search by title
    if (isset($params['find']) && $params['find']) {
        $q->where('AND', 'n.title', 'LIKE', '%' . $params['find'] . '%');
    }

    # Handling of sorting
    if (isset($params['order'])) {
        if ($params['order'] == 'title') {
            $orderStr = 'n.title';

        } else {
            $orderStr = 'n.updated_on';
        }

        if ($params['order'] == 'title') {
            $orderStr = 'n.title';

        } else {
            $orderStr = 'n.updated_on';
        }

        $q->orderBy($orderStr);

    } else {
        // Default sorting
        $q->orderBy('n.updated_on DESC');
    }

    if (isset($params['limit'])) {
        $q->limit($params['limit'], isset($params['offset']) ? $params['offset'] : 0);
    }

    $res = $this->db->execute($q);

    $notes = array();

    while ($row = $res->fetchRow()) {
        $notes[$row->uuid] = $this->fromRow($row);
    }

    return $notes;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

The method *persists the note to the database*. If that's what it's supposed to do, then that's a single responsibility and the implementation is fine. You'll need to put the logic of deciding whether to insert or update *somewhere*, this seems as good a place as any.

Only if you ever needed to explicitly do inserts or updates without the implicit decision logic would it be worthwhile to separate those two out into different methods which can be called separately. But at the moment, keeping them in the same method simplifies the code (since the latter half is shared), so that's likely the best implementation.

Exempli gratia:

```
public function save(Note $note) {
    if (..) {
        $this->insert($note);
    } else {
        $this->update($note);
    }
}

public function insert(Note $note) {
    ..
}

public function update(Note $note) {
    ..
}
```

The above would make sense if you sometimes needed to call `insert` or `update` explicitly for whatever reason. SRP is not really a reason for this separation though.

Comment: thanks. what about the method in my edit above. it is for listing notes and searching notes at the same time for instance. is it ok to do that or should i separate them? is it violating SRP then?

Comment: Well, that method's responsibility is to take an array of search criteria and return a list of notes. It's always the same thing. Even if the implementation may be rather complex and could possibly be refactored into separate methods for cleanliness, the SRP is not violated. SRP in a nutshell means that you should be able to describe what a method/class/module does in one short sentence. As soon as you need to describe it with *this X does foo, bar, baz and it also makes coffee*, it's probably violating the SRP.

Comment: *"Takes argument X and returns result Y"* is one responsibility. An example of *too much* would be: *"This class manages the database connection, and serialises the data, and renders the template, and caches the response"*.

Comment: Thanks but I don't quit understand what this means - `The method persists the note to the database.` - what does `persists` mean here?

Comment: It's useful to think about this in terms of "persistent storage". You can create a `Note` object *in memory* and work with it all you want, but as soon as your script ends the object will be gone. Because it was not *persisted* anywhere. A database (or any other storage mechanism for that matter) merely *persists* the object so you can use it again later. It just means "saves to the database", but conceptually it can help differentiating between *"the database is my core"* and *"the database merely holds onto my object data"*.

Comment: In terms of why this way of thinking is useful: your `getBy` method is currently focusing on building one giant SQL query which will return the exact data you want, and thereby this method is pretty complex. However, if you think about it in terms of a method which returns an array of objects, it doesn't really matter how those object came to be. You can probably break up that method into doing several smaller queries and then assembling the results into objects, instead of requiring the SQL to return exactly your object data in one result.

Answer (score 1):

SOLID principles are applied to class-level terminology, they don't explicitly state about methods. A SRP itself states, that classes should have one reason to change, so as long as you can replace a responsibility which is wrapped into one class, you're okay.

Consider this:

```
$userMapper = new Mapper\MySQL();
// or
$userMapper = new Mapper\Mongo();
// or
$userMapper = new Mapper\ArangoDb();

$userService = new UserService($userMapper);
```

All those mappers implement one interface and serve one responsibility - they do abstract storage access for users. Therefore mappers have one reason to change since you can swap them easily.

Your case is not about the SRP generally. It's more about best-practice. Well, the best practice regarding methods states that they should do only one thing whenever possible and accept as less arguments as possible. That makes it easier to read and find bugs.

There's one more principle which is called [Principle of Least Astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). It simply states that method names should explicitly do what their names imply.

Coming down to your code example:

The `save()` implies that it's all about data saving (updating existing record), not creating. By doing both insert and update there, you break the PoLA.

That's it, when you call explicitly `insert()` you know and expect that it will add a new record. The same about `update()` method - you know and expect that it will update a method, it will not create a new one.

Therefore I won't do both things in `save()`. If I want to update a record, I would call `update()`. If I want to create a record I would call `insert()`.

Comment: I'd disagree that `save` implies only insert or update. `save` to me is equivalent to `persist`, in which case I do not care what the underlying implementation does, only that I will be able to retrieve that data again next time I ask for it.

Comment: @deceze How would you comment `save()` regarding the PoLS then? And when testing in isolation, is it still going to be better (in terms of expectations and readability) than  2 methods `insert()` and `update()`?

Comment: There's a term that's pretty common for this operation: upsert. I don't know if anyone's ever been astonished by what an upsert does. I would argue on your side that the current implementation of `save` isn't sound (based on whether the object has an id, not on whether that id actually exists in the database), but the operation itself is quite simple and self explanatory if you view the database as an abstract object storage.